# Modifying how TTS speaks a string of capital letters

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In certain (quantifiable by my program) circumstances I want the tts engine to speak a string of letters as their own names rather than what they spell.

For example, in the square with corners named A, B, C, & D, I want it to speak the name of the line AB as "ay bee". At the moment it says "ab".

Can I do this? And, obviously, if so, how?

Comment: add spaces between alphabets and feed it to TTS?

Comment: Yes, but.

You're generally right (why didn't I think of that?), and also very fast! Thank you.

However, it still has problems with "A", which it continues to insist on pronouncing as "uh" rather than "ay".

Comment: In fact this only seems to happen with "A" at the beginning of a sentence, which seems particularly odd. Perhaps it's a US voice thing? I haven't yet been able to load the UK voice into my emulated device.

Comment: post your code, although you can fetch list of available languages using [getAvailableLanguages()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getAvailableLanguages())

Answer (score 1):

[As suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267668/modifying-how-tts-speaks-a-string-of-capital-letters/47269274#comment81486341_47267668) You can add spaces between alphabets and feed the it to TTS.

```
String a_z="A B C ...";
```

or if it is coming from some input source then do

```
input = "ABCDE".replaceAll("([A-Z])"," $1").trim()
```

where `([A-Z])` mean capture any capital alphabet which is represented by `$1`

and you can use [`setSpeechRate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setSpeechRate(float)) to stretch the speed to make it sounds as required.